# QuickFIX/n error: Tag appears more than once (Field=523)

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixn

My QuickFIX/n 5.0SP2 application is rejecting the R message with error - Tag appears more than once (Field=523). I have looked at all the similar issues on this site and the suggested solutions are not working for me. I have UseDataDictionary=Y in the settings. I have tried with Validate options set to Y and N. The message contains custom fields which I have added to the application data dictionary. I have checked the order of all the fields and it looks good. I tried using QuickFix.Net.NETCore.FIX50SP2 and QuickFIXn.FIX5.0SP2 nuget packages in case there was a difference in message parsing.

Some fields are not received in the correct order as per the standard FIX protocol. I have updated the order of the data dictionary fields to match the order of fields in the message. Could the order still be causing the message reject?

To confirm that the correct data dictionary is being picked, I tried adding a new required field and my application rejected the message, as expected, saying the required tag was missing.

I have been stuck on this error for a week now, any help would be highly appreciated!

Rejected message: 20210924-05:09:21.123 : 8=FIXT.1.1 9=123 35=R 34=234 52=20210924-05:09:21.721 49=XYZ 56=ABC 131=LST1 46=1 55=110K MAX 828=57 60=20210924-05:09:21 75=20210924 464=Y 20086=1 20073=REQ 20074=N 20075=N 20076=N 20077=[N/A] 20078=[N/A] 20079=5 20081=300 453=2 448=xyz 447=C 452=3 802=3 523=Shruti B 803=2 523=NY 803=25 523=US 803=4000 448=Customer 447=C 452=1 802=1 523=123 803=4002 5745=1 48=123ABC 22=1 460=10 167=MBS 762=MBSSPL 15=USD 64=20211015 541=20510920 223=2 38=1000000 54=1 699=1ABC2 761=1 423=12 228=1.0 58=Test DN 092401 10=209

SessionSettings

```
# default settings for sessions-->
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
ResetOnLogon=N
ResetOnLogout=Y
LogonTimeout=60
UseLocalTime=Y
FileLogPath=/fix_logs

# session definition
[SESSION]
# inherit FileLogPath, ConnectionType,
#    ReconnectInterval from default
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
SenderCompID=XYZ
TargetCompID=ABC
StartDay=monday
EndDay=saturday
StartTime=00:30:00
EndTime=18:16:00
HeartBtInt=60
CheckLatency=N
MaxLatency=240
UseDataDictionary=Y
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
SocketConnectPort=xxxxx
SocketConnectHost=xxx.xx.xx.xxx
FileStorePath=/file_store
TransportDataDictionary=FIXT11.xml
AppDataDictionary=FIX50SP2.xml
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=Y
ValidateFieldsHaveValues=Y
ValidateUserDefinedFields=Y
```

Partial Dictionary

```
<fix type="FIX" major="5" minor="0" servicepack="2">
    <header/>
    <messages>
        <message name="QuoteRequest" msgtype="R" msgcat="app">
            <field name="QuoteReqID" required="Y"/>
            <component name="QuotReqGrp" required="Y"/>
            <component name="Parties" required="Y"/>
            <field name="MultipleTickets" required="N"/>
            <field name="SecurityID" required="N"/>
            <field name="SecurityIDSource" required="N"/>
            <field name="Product" required="N"/>
            <field name="SecurityType" required="N"/>
            <field name="SecuritySubType" required="N"/>
            <field name="Currency" required="N"/>
            <field name="SettlDate" required="N"/>
            <field name="MaturityDate" required="N"/>
            <field name="CouponRate" required="N"/>
            <component name="OrderQtyData" required="N"/>
            <field name="Side" required="N"/>
            <component name="SpreadOrBenchmarkCurveData" required="N"/>
            <field name="PriceType" required="N"/>
            <field name="Factor" required="N"/>
            <field name="Text" required="N"/>
            <field name="EncodedTextLen" required="N"/>
            <field name="EncodedText" required="N"/>
            <field name="BookingType" required="N"/>
            <field name="OrderRestrictions" required="N"/>
        </message>
    </messages>
    <trailer/>
    <components>
        <component name="QuotReqGrp">
                <field name="NoRelatedSym" required="Y"/>
                <field name="Symbol" required="Y"/>
                <field name="SymbolSfx" required="N"/>
                <field name="TrdType" required="N"/>
                <field name="TransactTime" required="Y"/>
                <field name="TradeDate" required="Y"/>
                <field name="TestMessageIndicator" required="N"/>
                <field name="NoOfDealers" required="N"/>
                <field name="NegotiationType" required="N"/>
                <field name="CanRespond" required="N"/>
                <field name="CanQuote" required="N"/>
                    <field name="CanRequote" required="N"/>
                    <field name="BookName" required="N"/>
                    <field name="TraderList" required="N"/>
                    <field name="TimeoutPeriod" required="N"/>
                    <field name="NewTimePeriod" required="N"/>
                    <field name="QuoteTimePeriod" required="N"/>
                    <field name="ConfirmTimePeriod" required="N"/>
                    <field name="RequoteTimePeriod" required="N"/>
                <!--<field name="Price" required="Y"/>-->
        </component>
        <component name="Parties">
            <group name="NoPartyIDs" required="Y">
                <!--<field name="NoPartyIDs" required="Y"/>-->
                <field name="PartyID" required="Y"/>
                <field name="PartyIDSource" required="N"/>
                <field name="PartyRole" required="N"/>
                <component name="PtysSubGrp" required="Y"/>
            </group>
        </component>
        <component name="PtysSubGrp">
            <group name="NoPartySubIDs" required="Y">
                <field name="PartySubID" required="Y"/>
                <field name="PartySubIDType" required="Y"/>
            </group>
        </component>
        <component name="OrderQtyData">
            <field name="OrderQty" required="N"/>
            <field name="CashOrderQty" required="N"/>
            <field name="OrderPercent" required="N"/>
            <field name="RoundingDirection" required="N"/>
            <field name="RoundingModulus" required="N"/>
        </component>
        <component name="SpreadOrBenchmarkCurveData">
            <field name="Spread" required="N"/>
            <field name="BenchmarkCurveCurrency" required="N"/>
            <field name="BenchmarkCurveName" required="N"/>
            <field name="BenchmarkCurvePoint" required="N"/>
            <field name="BenchmarkPrice" required="N"/>
            <field name="BenchmarkPriceType" required="N"/>
            <field name="BenchmarkSecurityID" required="N"/>
            <field name="BenchmarkSecurityIDSource" required="N"/>
        </component>
    </components>
    <fields>
    </fields>
</fix>
```

Comment: Hi Shruti, can you confirm that you have followed the following: https://quickfixn.org/tutorial/custom-fields-groups-and-messages.html?

Comment: @TT. Yes, I checked this link and it looked pretty straightforward . I have updated the original question with part of the dictionary I'm using. To ensure I have all the fields in order and to make it cleaner, I removed all the extra messages and components. I also added most of the tags into the main QuoteRequest message. I have confirmed that each field in the message is defined in the fields section.

Comment: @TT. - If I add a dummy required field, say field 9999, in the NoPartyIDs group as the first field in the group I don't get a required tag missing error. Instead I still get the duplicate tag error. However, when I change the NoPartyIDs to a field, I get a error for the required tag. So, looks like when QuickFIX encounters a group, it processes the innermost group within that parent group and then works outward. There are only 2 fields in the NoPartySubIDs group and the message has the 2 fields, 523 and 803, in the same order.

Comment: @TT. As per the incoming message, the Parties component should have been within the QuotReqGrp component. I corrected it, and also removed the component tag and just went with group tags. I am able to read the message in my code now, thank you!

Comment: You're quite welcome. Can you answer your own question outlining the steps you took to solve your problem? That can help future visitors with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the presence of custom fields in the incoming message that were missing in my data dictionary. At some point, while attempting to add these custom fields and cleaning up the dictionary, I removed the Parties component from the QuotReqGrp component and placed it after QuotReqGrp. I started again with a fresh copy of the data dictionary and added the custom fields to resolve the issue.